# onKeyDown event on <li> react

Tags: reactjs

I am having Autocomplete class  (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-react-autocomplete) with input fragment for searching and suggestions list in "li" component. I want to add listener (onKeyDown) on suggestions. Like when user press enter on suggestion, it will appeared in input field. What is working is onClick handler so I want to call the same function. But OnkeyDown isn't logging anything.

Any idea? I was thinking, maybe focus problem? I can see the input has cofus active even though I am using arrows to scroll down in suggestions list. So it listeners only on input field? what to do with it?

```
  suggestionsListComponent = (
            <ul className="suggestions" > {
                    filteredSuggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
                        let className;

                        // Flag the active suggestion with a class
                        if (index === activeSuggestion) {
                            className = "suggestion-active";
                        }

                        return (<li className={className}
                            key={suggestion}
                            onClick={onClick }
                            onKeyDown={onkeyDownSuggestions }
                        > {suggestion} </li>
                        );
                    })
                } </ul>
            );


 <Fragment>
        <input
            type="text"
            onChange={onChange}
            onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
            value={userInput}
            id="searchBar"
        />
        {suggestionsListComponent}
    </Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your li element a `tabIndex={0}` prop so it can be focused. Then it will catch keyPress event. But this will not make it focusable with down arrow key. You can focus using tab key. If you want to focus with arrow keys, you probably will need to use `focus()` manually. Then you will need `tabIndex={-1}`

Comment: Tried `tabIndex={0}` not working 

       `onKeyDown={() => console.log("works!"}
       tabIndex={0}`

Comment: Works for me, check this example I made: https://jsitor.com/U-rHA09ZRR

Comment: how to adjust scroll bar position automatically based on key down event in the same example

Comment: The link seems to not work anymore but you can use eg.
`el.focus(); el.scrollIntoView();`